# Classic ASP code migration

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vbscript, asp-classic, barcode

I am trying to migrate some code from Classic ASP/VBScript.

This code shown below generates a barcode. As it is known, some functions do not exist or are entirely different in .NET. So I figured I would  thrown the old code, in the code-behind of my `barcode.aspx` page (as I call the barcode generation sequence like this:
 `<img src="/barcode.aspx?code="<%: getID(sheet_id)%>" border="0" height="80"/>`

This is the Classic code:

```
<%
Option Explicit
Response.CodePage = 1252 
Response.CharSet = "windows-1252"
Response.Contenttype = "image/bmp"

' code = bar code value
' height = height of barcode in pixels.
' width = width MULTIPLIER in pixels.
' mode = type of barcode (Currently supported barcode types: code39, code128b, UPC-A, EAN-13)
' 

dim code, origcode, height, width, mode, caching, FontKey, FontCN10, FontCN12

caching = False ' turn this on to cache barcodes in '10101010' format. Might speed things up on busy servers, although this script doesn't take many resources to begin with. An EAN-13 or UPC barcode will take less than 100 bytes of memory space. Other types will take more or less depending on the length of the barcode created.
' DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE!

code        = Request.QueryString("code")
height      = 80        'request.querystring("height")
width       = 2     'request.querystring("width")
mode        = "code39"  'request.querystring("mode")
origcode    = code

if not IsNumeric(height) or height  = "" then   height  = 1 else height = numeric(height)
if not IsNumeric(width) or width        = "" then   width       = 1 else width      = numeric(width)
if caching AND application("cache" & origcode & mode & height & width) <> "" then
    code    = application("cache" & origcode & mode & height & width)
else
    select case lcase(mode)
        case "raw"          ' do nothing. non-0 chars are automatically 1s
        case "code39":      code    = code39(code)
        case "code128b":    code    = code128b(code)
        case "upc-a":       code    = codeean13("0" & code, "AAAAAA")
        case "ean-13":      code    = codeean13(code, eanflag(left(code, 1)))
    end select
    if caching then
        Application.Lock
        Application("cache" & origcode & mode & height & width) = code
        Application.UnLock
    end if
end if

Function stb(String)
 Dim I, B
 For I=1 to len(String)
 B  = B & ChrB(Asc(Mid(String,I,1)))
 Next
 stb    = B
End Function

function tstr(data, width)
    dim tchar, total, tpos, i, j, x
    tchar   = 0
    total   = ""
    tpos    = 8
    for i   = 1 to len(data)
        for j   = 1 to width
            tpos        = tpos - 1
            if mid(data, i, 1) <> "0" then tchar    = tchar + 2^tpos
            if tpos = 0 then
                total   = total & chr(tchar)
                tpos    = 8
                tchar   = 0
            end if
        next
    next
    if tpos <> 8 then
        total   = total & chr(tchar)
    end if
    x       = len(total) mod 4
    if x    = 0 then x  = 4
    for i   = x to 3
        total   = total & chr(0)
    next
    tstr    = total
end function
function numeric(num)
    dim numb, valid, i
    numb    = ""
    valid   = "0123456789"
    for i   = 1 to len(num)
        if InStr(valid, mid(num, i, 1)) > 0 then numb   = numb & mid(num, i, 1)
    next
    num     = left(num, 30)
    numeric = cint(num)
end function
function size(lngth)
    lngth   = cdbl(lngth)
    if lngth    > 255 then
        if lngth > 65535 then lngth = 65535
        size    = chr(lngth mod 256) & chr(int(lngth/256))
    else
        size    = chr(lngth) & chr(0)
    end if
end function
function code39(code)
    dim output, i, clet
    output  = ""
    code        = "*" & replace(code, "*", "") & "*"
    for i   = 1 to len(code)
        clet    = ""
        select case ucase(mid(code, i, 1))
            case "1": clet  = "111010001010111"
            case "2": clet  = "101110001010111"
            case "3": clet  = "111011100010101"
            case "4": clet  = "101000111010111"
            case "5": clet  = "111010001110101"
            case "6": clet  = "101110001110101"
            case "7": clet  = "101000101110111"
            case "8": clet  = "111010001011101"
            case "9": clet  = "101110001011101"
            case "0": clet  = "101000111011101"
            case "A": clet  = "111010100010111"
            case "B": clet  = "101110100010111"
            case "C": clet  = "111011101000101"
            case "D": clet  = "101011100010111"
            case "E": clet  = "111010111000101"
            case "F": clet  = "101110111000101"
            case "G": clet  = "101010001110111"
            case "H": clet  = "111010100011101"
            case "I": clet  = "101110100011101"
            case "J": clet  = "101011100011101"
            case "K": clet  = "111010101000111"
            case "L": clet  = "101110101000111"
            case "M": clet  = "111011101010001"
            case "N": clet  = "101011101000111"
            case "O": clet  = "111010111010001"
            case "P": clet  = "101110111010001"
            case "Q": clet  = "101010111000111"
            case "R": clet  = "111010101110001"
            case "S": clet  = "101110101110001"
            case "T": clet  = "101011101110001"
            case "U": clet  = "111000101010111"
            case "V": clet  = "100011101010111"
            case "W": clet  = "111000111010101"
            case "X": clet  = "100010111010111"
            case "Y": clet  = "111000101110101"
            case "Z": clet  = "100011101110101"
            case "-": clet  = "100010101110111"
            case ".": clet  = "111000101011101"
            case " ": clet  = "100011101011101"
            case "*": clet  = "100010111011101"
            case "$": clet  = "100010001000101"
            case "/": clet  = "100010001010001"
            case "+": clet  = "100010100010001"
            case "%": clet  = "101000100010001"
        end select
        output  = output & clet & "0"
    next
    code39      = left(output, len(output)-1)
end function
Function code128b(ByVal InputString)
    Const MinValidAscii = 32
    Const MaxValidAscii = 126
    Dim CharValue(255)
    Dim i
    for i   = 0 to 94
        CharValue(i+32) = i
    next
    for i   = 95 to 106
        CharValue(i+100)    = i
    next
    ' Encode the input string
    InputString = Trim(InputString)
    Dim CheckDigitValue, CharPos, CharAscii, InvalidCharsFound
    InvalidCharsFound   = false
    CheckDigitValue = CharValue(204)
    For CharPos = 1 To Len(InputString)
        CharAscii       = Asc(Mid(InputString, CharPos, 1))
        if (CharAscii < MinValidAscii) OR (CharAscii > MaxValidAscii) then
            CharAscii           = Asc("?")
            InvalidCharsFound   = true
        end if
        CheckDigitValue = CheckDigitValue + (CharValue(CharAscii) * CharPos)
    Next
    CheckDigitValue     = (CheckDigitValue Mod 103)
    Dim CheckDigitAscii
    if CheckDigitValue < 95 then
        CheckDigitAscii = CheckDigitValue + 32
    else
        CheckDigitAscii = CheckDigitValue + 100
    end if
    Dim OutputString
    OutputString            = Chr(204) & InputString & Chr(CheckDigitAscii) & Chr(206)
    Dim BarcodePattern(255)
    BarcodePattern(32)  = "212222"      ' <SPACE>
    BarcodePattern(33)  = "222122"      ' !
    BarcodePattern(34)  = "222221"      ' "
    BarcodePattern(35)  = "121223"      ' #
    BarcodePattern(36)  = "121322"      ' $
    BarcodePattern(37)  = "131222"      ' %
    BarcodePattern(38)  = "122213"      ' &
    BarcodePattern(39)  = "122312"      ' '
    BarcodePattern(40)  = "132212"      ' (
    BarcodePattern(41)  = "221213"      ' )
    BarcodePattern(42)  = "221312"      ' *
    BarcodePattern(43)  = "231212"      ' +
    BarcodePattern(44)  = "112232"      ' ,
    BarcodePattern(45)  = "122132"      ' -
    BarcodePattern(46)  = "122231"      ' .
    BarcodePattern(47)  = "113222"      ' /
    BarcodePattern(48)  = "123122"      ' 0
    BarcodePattern(49)  = "123221"      ' 1
    BarcodePattern(50)  = "223211"      ' 2
    BarcodePattern(51)  = "221132"      ' 3
    BarcodePattern(52)  = "221231"      ' 4
    BarcodePattern(53)  = "213212"      ' 5
    BarcodePattern(54)  = "223112"      ' 6
    BarcodePattern(55)  = "312131"      ' 7
    BarcodePattern(56)  = "311222"      ' 8
    BarcodePattern(57)  = "321122"      ' 9
    BarcodePattern(58)  = "321221"      ' :
    BarcodePattern(59)  = "312212"      ' ;
    BarcodePattern(60)  = "322112"      ' <
    BarcodePattern(61)  = "322211"      ' =
    BarcodePattern(62)  = "212123"      ' >
    BarcodePattern(63)  = "212321"      ' ?
    BarcodePattern(64)  = "232121"      ' @
    BarcodePattern(65)  = "111323"      ' A
    BarcodePattern(66)  = "131123"      ' B
    BarcodePattern(67)  = "131321"      ' C
    BarcodePattern(68)  = "112313"      ' D
    BarcodePattern(69)  = "132113"      ' E
    BarcodePattern(70)  = "132311"      ' F
    BarcodePattern(71)  = "211313"      ' G
    BarcodePattern(72)  = "231113"      ' H
    BarcodePattern(73)  = "231311"      ' I
    BarcodePattern(74)  = "112133"      ' J
    BarcodePattern(75)  = "112331"      ' K
    BarcodePattern(76)  = "132131"      ' L
    BarcodePattern(77)  = "113123"      ' M
    BarcodePattern(78)  = "113321"      ' N
    BarcodePattern(79)  = "133121"      ' O
    BarcodePattern(80)  = "313121"      ' P
    BarcodePattern(81)  = "211331"      ' Q
    BarcodePattern(82)  = "231131"      ' R
    BarcodePattern(83)  = "213113"      ' S
    BarcodePattern(84)  = "213311"      ' T
    BarcodePattern(85)  = "213131"      ' U
    BarcodePattern(86)  = "311123"      ' V
    BarcodePattern(87)  = "311321"      ' W
    BarcodePattern(88)  = "331121"      ' X
    BarcodePattern(89)  = "312113"      ' Y
    BarcodePattern(90)  = "312311"      ' Z
    BarcodePattern(91)  = "332111"      ' [
    BarcodePattern(92)  = "314111"      ' /
    BarcodePattern(93)  = "221411"      ' ]
    BarcodePattern(94)  = "431111"      ' ^
    BarcodePattern(95)  = "111224"      ' _
    BarcodePattern(96)  = "111422"      ' `
    BarcodePattern(97)  = "121124"      ' a
    BarcodePattern(98)  = "121421"      ' b
    BarcodePattern(99)  = "141122"      ' c
    BarcodePattern(100) = "141221"      ' d
    BarcodePattern(101) = "112214"      ' e
    BarcodePattern(102) = "112412"      ' f
    BarcodePattern(103) = "122114"      ' g
    BarcodePattern(104) = "122411"      ' h
    BarcodePattern(105) = "142112"      ' i
    BarcodePattern(106) = "142211"      ' j
    BarcodePattern(107) = "241211"      ' k
    BarcodePattern(108) = "221114"      ' l
    BarcodePattern(109) = "413111"      ' m
    BarcodePattern(110) = "241112"      ' n
    BarcodePattern(111) = "134111"      ' o
    BarcodePattern(112) = "111242"      ' p
    BarcodePattern(113) = "121142"      ' q
    BarcodePattern(114) = "121241"      ' r
    BarcodePattern(115) = "114212"      ' s
    BarcodePattern(116) = "124112"      ' t
    BarcodePattern(117) = "124211"      ' u
    BarcodePattern(118) = "411212"      ' v
    BarcodePattern(119) = "421112"      ' w
    BarcodePattern(120) = "421211"      ' x
    BarcodePattern(121) = "212141"      ' y
    BarcodePattern(122) = "214121"      ' z
    BarcodePattern(123) = "412121"      ' {
    BarcodePattern(124) = "111143"      ' |
    BarcodePattern(125) = "111341"      ' }
    BarcodePattern(126) = "131141"      ' ~
    BarcodePattern(195) = "114113"
    BarcodePattern(196) = "114311"
    BarcodePattern(197) = "411113"
    BarcodePattern(198) = "411311"
    BarcodePattern(199) = "113141"
    BarcodePattern(200) = "114131"
    BarcodePattern(201) = "311141"
    BarcodePattern(202) = "411131"
    BarcodePattern(203) = "211412"
    BarcodePattern(204) = "211214"
    BarcodePattern(205) = "211232"
    BarcodePattern(206) = "2331112"
    Dim OutputPattern, ThisPattern, thischar
    OutputPattern   = ""
    for CharPos     = 1 to Len(OutputString)
        ThisPattern = BarcodePattern(Asc(Mid(OutputString, CharPos, 1)))
        for i = 1 to len(ThisPattern)
            if i mod 2 = 1 then thischar    = "1" else thischar = "0"
            OutputPattern   = OutputPattern & replace(space(int(mid(ThisPattern, i, 1))), " ", thischar)
        next
    next
    code128b    = OutputPattern
End Function
Function CodeEAN13(code, encoding)
    Dim leftA, leftB, rght, OutputPattern, i
    if len(code) = 13 then
        LeftA   = Array("0001101", "0011001", "0010011", "0111101", "0100011", "0110001", "0101111", "0111011", "0110111", "0001011")
        LeftB   = Array("0100111", "0110011", "0011011", "0100001", "0011101", "0111001", "0000101", "0010001", "0001001", "0010111")
        Rght    = Array("1110010", "1100110", "1101100", "1000010", "1011100", "1001110", "1010000", "1000100", "1001000", "1110100")
        OutputPattern   = "101"
        for i = 1 to 6
            if mid(ucase(encoding), i, 1)   = "A" then
                OutputPattern   = OutputPattern & LeftA(cint(mid(code, i+1, 1)))
            else
                OutputPattern   = OutputPattern & LeftB(cint(mid(code, i+1, 1)))
            end if
        next
        OutputPattern       = OutputPattern & "01010"
        for i = 1 to 6
            OutputPattern   = OutputPattern & Rght(cint(mid(code, i+7, 1)))
        next
        OutputPattern       = OutputPattern & "101"
        CodeEAN13           = OutputPattern
    end if
End Function
Function eanflag(num)
    select case num
        case 0: eanflag = "AAAAAA"
        case 1: eanflag = "AABABB"
        case 2: eanflag = "AABBAB"
        case 3: eanflag = "AABBBA"
        case 4: eanflag = "ABAABB"
        case 5: eanflag = "ABBAAB"
        case 6: eanflag = "ABBBAA"
        case 7: eanflag = "ABABAB"
        case 8: eanflag = "ABABBA"
        case 9: eanflag = "ABBABA"
    end select
End Function
dim dataout, i
if code <> "" then
    dataout = tstr(code, width)
    response.binarywrite stb(chr(66) & chr(77) & size(62+(len(dataout)*height)) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(62) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(40) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(0) & size(len(code)*width) & chr(0) & chr(0) & size(height) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(1) & chr(0) & chr(1) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(37) & chr(14) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(37) & chr(14) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(255) & chr(255) & chr(255) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(0) & chr(0))
    for i   = 1 to height
        response.binarywrite stb(dataout)
    next
end if
%>
```

The stuff the are "problematic" (based on VS underlining) are:

```
For I = 1 To Len(text)
            B = B & ChrB(Asc(Mid(text, I, 1)))
        Next
```

and `Array` in `CodeEAN13` function, which I completely commented out since I am using `Code39`

I put this piece of code on code-behind of `barcode.aspx`'s page load:

```
 Response.Charset = "windows-1252"
        Response.ContentType = "image/bmp"

        Dim code, origcode, height, width, mode, caching, FontKey, FontCN10, FontCN12

        caching = False ' turn this on to cache barcodes in '10101010' format. Might speed things up on busy servers, although this script doesn't take many resources to begin with. An EAN-13 or UPC barcode will take less than 100 bytes of memory space. Other types will take more or less depending on the length of the barcode created.
        ' DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE!

        code = Request.QueryString("code")
        height = 80        'request.querystring("height")
        width = 2     'request.querystring("width")
        mode = "code39"  'request.querystring("mode")
        origcode = code

        If Not IsNumeric(height) Or height = "" Then height = 1 Else height = numeric(height)
        If Not IsNumeric(width) Or width = "" Then width = 1 Else width = numeric(width)
        If caching And Application("cache" & origcode & mode & height & width) <> "" Then
            code = Application("cache" & origcode & mode & height & width)
        Else
            Select Case LCase(mode)
                Case "raw"          ' do nothing. non-0 chars are automatically 1s
                Case "code39" : code = code39(code)
                Case "code128b" : code = code128b(code)
                    'Case "upc-a" : code = codeean13("0" & code, "AAAAAA")
                    'Case "ean-13" : code = codeean13(code, eanflag(Left(code, 1)))
            End Select
            If caching Then
                Application.Lock()
                Application("cache" & origcode & mode & height & width) = code
                Application.UnLock()
            End If
        End If



 If code <> "" Then
        dataout = tstr(code, width)
        Response.BinaryWrite(stb(Chr(66) & Chr(77) & size(62 + (Len(dataout) * height)) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(62) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(40) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & size(Len(code) * width) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & size(height) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(1) & Chr(0) & Chr(1) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(37) & Chr(14) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(37) & Chr(14) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(255) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(0)))
        For i = 1 To height
            Response.BinaryWrite(stb(dataout))
        Next
    End If
```

Also, I tried changing

```
Function stb(text)
        Dim I, B
        For I = 1 To Len(text)
            B = B & ChrB(Asc(Mid(text, I, 1)))
        Next
        stb = B
    End Function
```

to

```
Function stb(text)
        Dim I, B
        For I = 1 To Len(text)
            B = B & Convert.ToChar(Asc(Mid(text, I, 1)))
        Next
        stb = B
    End Function
```

Well, needless to say, it does not work :)

Comment: This is too broad to be answered. When you say it doesn't work - what doesn't work? Is there an exception thrown? The incorrect output?

Comment: no exceptions. I just get a nearly all-black image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after several hours of sweating and beating myself, I have used another solution.I will post it here for anyone that might have similar problems.

What I did was basically using  the **[Barcode Rendering Framework](http://barcoderender.codeplex.com)**

As no clear documentation exists for this library, I will explain the procedure below:

1. Download the library from the link above.
2. Add a reference to your project, browsing to `Zen.Barcode.Core.dll`
3. Import `zen.barcode` in your code-behind
4. The rest is in my code :)

   ```
   Dim sheet_id As String = Session("generated_id")
   Dim height As Integer = 80

   Dim width As Integer = 80
   'Dim mode As String = "code39"

   Dim bar As Code39BarcodeDraw = BarcodeDrawFactory.Code39WithoutChecksum

   Dim img As Image = bar.Draw(sheet_id, height, width)
   Dim bmp As Bitmap = img
   Dim stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream

   bmp.Save(stream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
   stream.Position = 0
   Dim size As Integer = stream.Length
   Dim data(stream.Length) As Byte

   stream.Read(data, 0, stream.Length)

   Response.BinaryWrite(data)
   ```

The call is being made on the landing page's `body` like so:

`<img src="/barcode.aspx" border="0" height="80" width="250"/>`